# net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=8223329095323268490) with empty buffer

Tags: corda

```
class Initiator(private val notificationObject: NotificationModel, private val counterParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {

            val counterPartySession = initiateFlow(counterParty)
            val counterPartyData = counterPartySession.sendAndReceive<NotificationModel>(notificationObject)
            counterPartyData.unwrap { msg ->
                assert(msg.notification_data == notificationObject.notification_data)
            }
        }
    }
```

something is wrong at sendAndReceive. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to send notification object to counter party. It throws an error for sendAndReceive.

Comment: can you attach the responder flow code please

Comment: `@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
    class Acceptor(private val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call() {
            val counterPartyData = counterpartySession.receive<NotificationModel>()
            counterPartyData.unwrap { msg ->
                //code goes here
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the code.  It looks the the `Acceptor` isn't sending a message back to the `Initiator`?

Your `Initiator` calls `sendAndReceive<>` which means that it'll want to get something back from the `Acceptor`.  In this case the `Acceptor` isn't sending the response back so we see the `UnexpectedEndOfFLowException` (because the `Initiator` expected something back but didn't get it).

I suspect you'd want to add a line in to send the `NotificationModel` back:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(private val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() { 

    @Suspendable override fun call() { 
        val counterPartyData = counterpartySession.receive<NotificationModel>() 
        counterPartyData.unwrap { msg -> //code goes here } 
        counterPartySession.send(/* some payload of type NotificationModel here */)
    } 
}
```

See the following doc: https://docs.corda.net/api-flows.html#sendandreceive

Alternatively you could just call `send` on the `Initiator` if you don't expect a response back from the `Acceptor`: https://docs.corda.net/api-flows.html#send

Comment: Thanks @fowlerrr. I did the same and it worked for me.
Appreciate your quick response.
`counterpartySession.send(msg)` was missing in acceptor flow.